# How to add entry box together with checkbutton in python tkinter UI

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a checkbox bar. How to add entry box with each check button and disable entry box if checkbox is disabled?

code for creating checkbox is below

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
import os


class Checkbar(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.vars = []
      for pick in picks:
         var = IntVar(value=1)
         chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
         chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
         self.vars.append(var)
   def state(self):
       return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    lng = Checkbar(root, ['ASD', 'BSD', 'CSD'])
    lng.grid(row=0, columnspan=6)
```

Below is expected UI:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Entry` widgets in the same `for` loop and associate them to the `Checkbutton`.

```py
class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vars = []

        for pick in picks:
            var = IntVar(value=1)
            entry = Entry(self)
            chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var, command=lambda v=var, e=entry: self.show_entry(v,e))
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
            entry.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
            self.vars.append(var)

    def show_entry(self, var, widget):
        if var.get() == 0:
            widget.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            widget.configure(state='normal')
```

Comment: Thank you Henry. The problem is it does not create static entry box next to check button. Rather after checking checkbox it creates dynamic stack of entry boxes.

Comment: I don't understand you. The entries are already static - just type something inside and see.

Comment: I mean, entry box is created only after I tick checkbox.

Comment: Didn't you say "add entry box with each check button"? So what is your true expected output?

Comment: Henry,I am trying to create entry box with each check box by default it checkbox is checked and entry box is shown next to it. Added UI pic. Based on your answer I could create it. So suggested edit to answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see. Much easier to see when you have a sample pic but glad you got it sorted out.